# Pop up window on page load

Tags: php, html

I want to create a pop up window with text box and it will appear whenever I redirected to this page.
i found a code from w3schools but there i have to click the try it button then the pop -up window appears.

here is that code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

    if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.onload = myFunction;` this line in script tag, **FYI** popup will be blocked while you have not allowed once due browser security reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<body>` by `<body onload='myFunction()'>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways calling the function on page load

First one

```
<body onload='myFunction()'>
```

Second one

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

        if (person != null) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
        }
    }
    myFunction();
</script>
```

for second option, if the element is not loaded then it will throws undefined error. so it is better to write the script in footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/g78hgn2p/

html

```
<body onload='myFunction()'>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

js

```
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

if (person != null) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
}
}
 myFunction();
```